# How do I execute a SELECT query in a text string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a function `my_funct(param1,param2)` returning a `SELECT QUERY` as a `text`, I usually C/c the result, remove quotes, then run it.

**How can execute the returned text in a query that call the function ?**

I expect something like this:

```
    SELECT resultOf( myfunct('foo','bar'))
```

with no extra columnname/type to declare. If such function does not exits built-in, let's create it, I don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want

- Call a function returning a select query as text
- Run that query to get the result.
- Number and type of columns are dynamic

**1. Using Do Block:**

```
DO
$$
declare 
ref_cursor refcursor:='mycursor';
begin
open ref_cursor for execute (select * from my_funct('foo','bar')) ;
end;
$$;

--Fetch all data from cursor
Fetch all from mycursor;
```

**2. Using Function returning `refcursor`:**

You can create a function like below:

```
create function my_funct1(param1 text) returns refcursor as

$$
declare 
ref_cursor refcursor:='mycursor';
begin
open ref_cursor for execute param1;
return ref_cursor;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

To call above function use following code:

```
begin ;
select my_funct1((select * from my_funct('foo','bar')) );
fetch all from mycursor;
commit;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8cd4ed26e2216ce2a0bc610b18fe4849)